# CronTab not run

Tags: python, cron, centos

I installed CroneTab, open the editor using `crontab -e`
and for executing the following statement `python3.8 i.pyc` every 5 min I wrote

```
 5 * * * * #!/usr/bin/python3.8 i.pyc
```

Then, I made sure that no error using `sudo less /var/spool/mail/root` and saw the crone job in the list with `sudo grep CRON /var/log/cron`

But unfortunately, the corn is not running, I don't see the output file but if I write `python3.8 i.pyc`  without the crone, the statement works well.

What I missed ?

Comment: It's probably not looking in the right directory for the i.pyc file; try using the full path to that file. BTW, you may also run into trouble because cron jobs will not have any of your normal environment set up (e.g. `PYTHON_PATH` will not be defined, etc). For troubleshooting, add something like `>>/tmp/cronjob.log 2>&1` to the crontab entry, then look in that log file for error messages.

Comment: the file is located in the root, so I need to change it to  '5 * * * * #!/usr/bin/python3.8 /i.pyc' ?

Comment: If that's where it is, then yes.

Comment: I changed it to be '5 * * * * #!/usr/bin/python3.8 /i.pyc'  and it's the same, the crone not working

Comment: fwiw, i scratched my head for hours on a similar issue and it turned out you also need to ensure that you've left a blank line at the EOF, can't say thats's what's goin on, but may as well try

Comment: The hash sign makes the whole line a single comment. I wouldn't be surprised if nothing happens.

Comment: I copy pasted from the code: every commend per line

`*/5 * * * * #!/usr/bin/python3.8 /i.pyc /tmp/cronjob.log 2>&1

0 0 * * * #!/usr/bin/python3.8 /t.pyc
~
~
~
~
~
`

Comment: @ibug you right...... solved